# Best practices to protect over-air protocols

Tags: algorithm, security, md5

I’m developing a protocol for wireless communication between two microcontrollers, using a 433Mhz modem which can send serial data in a raw format (plain text if you want). I know that this sounds more like an electronic question but my problem is in the coding part, let me explain myself.

Let say that unit one send this command **“0x001/0x010/LIGHT1/ON”** (this is plain text) to unit 2, the first is unit 1 name, the second the unit 2 name, the third a actuator and the last one the action. All ok and working, BUT I want to give the system a little level of security, because if somebody is listening to that frequency using a technique like “men-in-the-middle” can easily copy the command and resend it any time he wants.

I was thinking about crypting the messages transmitted over air, but then again this will not protect the system against the same type of attack, let’s say I encrypt the message using something like MD5, I will transmit something like  **“767b79ebb8061054d3ad1eaef428b469”**, the attacker just need to copy that string and resend it to achieve the same result.

So how can I solve this? Take in consideration that I’m not controlling a nuclear reactor so I don’t need a very high level of security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that each node "knows" the nodes it is supposed to take commands from - in this case have the receiving node store a (simple) key for each node it will take commands from, then add three fields to the protocol:

- a salt (random number created by the sender)
- a sequence number
- an authentication field

Both sender and receiver store the last used sequence number for a tx->rx relation, the sender increases it with every command.

Both sender and receiver create a hash (SHA1?) of the concatenation `SequenceNumber+Command+SequenceNumber+salt+nodekey`

**Edit:** `nodekey` ist the **sending** node's key

The sender sends this as the authentication field, the receiver checks it against the authentication field and accepts the command only, if the sequence number is higher than the LRU sequence number and the authentication field checks out OK.

This is secure against a replay attack, as it would involve a sequence number reuse.

**Edit:**

There is concern in the comments about loss of synchronity in the sequence numbers, but the proposed solution is resiliant against that: Only the **sender** will ever increase the SN, and the receiver will accept all SNs higher than the last used. Loss of a message will make the SN jump, but it will still be accepted as higher than LRU.

Comment: I think it's important to consider data loss/corruption which can lead to the sequence numbers going out of sync on both ends.

Comment: @Alex I was thinking just about that

Answer (score 1):

> let’s say I encrypt the message using something like MD5, I will
>   transmit something like “767b79ebb8061054d3ad1eaef428b469”,

You don't encrypt with MD5. You send the hash of the command. And this means that on the receiving side you need to have an inverse-look up table to map the message digest you send to the corresponding command.

> the attacker just need to copy that string and resend it to achieve the
>   same result.

This is a valid concern and it falls in the category of [Replay Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack). There are plenty of ways to address this, but it requires quite a bit of effort from your side to re-design both your transmitters and receivers

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on a micro controller I supose you don't have the most advanced encryption functiuns and something easy to implement is mostly the best way to go imo.

If you have MD5 available on your controller I would use Eugen Rieck method except I would just say, you can only use every key once every lets say 10 days or something (depending on how much data you send ofc).

This makes it already a bit more secure and except if they do some long term listening they won't be able to use your commands.

Keep in mind this is somekind of [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and if they attacker knows it just has a 10 day cool down it won't work.

If you do have encryption functions and curent time onboard of you device I would just use basic a basic encryption function with the current time.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider using some kind of encryption that relies on a key. The key, of course, will probably have to be determined in some way that both controllers can keep in sync with - perhaps some means of using the time of day would be sufficient. Something like PHP's `time()` function, rounded to the nearest hundred. Each controller, when it gets a signal, could check the current rounded timestamp and the previous, so if an attacker got an encrypted signal it would only be reusable for a maximum of 200 seconds. Depending on the time it takes to transmit each signal and the level of security needed (and possibly how often you can get away with a missed signal), you might round to ten or five seconds. With some pseudo-code (rounding to ten):

**Sending:**

```
signal=encrypt(outgoing, round(time, 10))
sendSignal(signal)
```

**Receiving:**

```
signal=decrypt(incoming, round(time, 10))
if (invalid(signal)) {signal=decrypt(incoming, round(time, 10)-10)}
interpretSignal(signal)
```

You would, as indicated by the second line, need some way of determining if the decrypted signal is valid.

This is what I thought up for a common key mechanism that should always be fairly in-sync. The basic idea, though, is to encrypt the signals with a frequently changing key that the senders and receivers all know, or can determine.